# How to zoom in display of device for android?

Tags: android, screen, zooming

I want zoom in display of device itself without rooting.

for example..
like zoom in home screen.

Is this way exist?

Comment: Hello, Did you solved this ? I need to do same like this question. How you solve this ?

Comment: Hello. I already gave up...
I didn't solved this.

Comment: Hmmm :( okey. I want to do this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843299/can-we-implement-magnification-gesture-using-our-own-apps

Comment: I also want imitate this function(Magnification gestures). But... It's so difficult..... Anyway, I hope you will solve this problem :)

Comment: Hmmm, I am not thiking to gave up.... but i need to gave up :( :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is inappropriate as it's not a programming question. However what you want is [magnification gestures](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2929058?hl=en&ref_topic=3453509). This was included into Android 4.1 but may not be included by all manufacturers.

Comment: That's right.  
I wanna make app using the that function.  
But,, I can't find API or example code about that function.

Comment: It's not part of the API as it's an accessibility feature. If you want to allow a user to scale your app then just make sure you are always using dips (device independent pixels). Then a user can simply change their accessibility options of Android and your app will scale appropriately. It's still not clear to me what you're asking for.