# Can we implement Magnification gesture using our own apps?

Tags: android, gesture, magnification

I need to implement Magnification Gesture using my android application. **Some or all of this information applies only to Nexus 7 devices running Android 4.2.**

Check more about [Magnification Gesture](http://pauljadam.com/androida11y/#magnification).

[image]

[image]

I need to apply percentage level of zoom in and zoom out using my android applicatoin.

Is it possible to do or not ?

I have searched but nothing find related to this.

**EDIT**

Can we perform same effect zoom in - zoom out bellow Android 4.2 ?

Comment: in case for text zooming..i think webview will work..need to try and see

Comment: @Monicka I need to implement zooming in phone with in any app or HomeScreen etc. Its global zooming for entire phone.

Comment: @Prince: I am nearly one year late from the date you posted. Whether you got any workaround for your question. If yes can you please give me the workaround. I wish to implement the global magnification glass effect from my custom application. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Nop buddy. I didnt get any clue, and i dont think we can do it. but if you found any solution then you can share anytime :) All the best.